# defining a block of memory in flash as variables in IAR

Tags: memory, stm32, iar

I'm developing on STM32 mC using IAR 7.80.
I need to represent a specific block of memory in flash as variables of different sizes.
for example starting from location 0x0800B00 I have the following data:
4 bytes that are a float, an array of chars of size 4 and then 4 bytes that are a uint32_t.
currently I specify the specific location of each variable so that for the above example I write:

```
_Pragma("location=0x0800B000") const float    first_var = 5.0;
_Pragma("location=0x0800B004") const char[4]  second_var = {1,2,3,4};
_Pragma("location=0x0800B008") const uint32_t third_var = 1000;
```

in reality I have more than 100 such variables and adding/removing variables is frequent in this stage of development, thus, each time I remove a variable I need to either rearrange the locations of all the variables of leave gaps!
Is there a better way to represent these variables?
note: I need to be able to take the memory block and parse it in a PC application , therefore, I need that each variable occupy it's size exactly and not more!

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient way to solve this problem is to use one struct with a number of separate fields, one for each variables, instead of a set of individual variables. With this solution you only have to specify the location once, you are guaranteed that the fields are placed in the order you want and, if you use a packed struct, you can mix fields of different sizes and still ensure that there is no padding between them. The only price you pay for this is the prefix needed to transform variable accesses to struct accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach is to specify your variables in a file format that is very easy to parse. You could use CSV for example, and define type, name, and default value in different columns.

Then use scripting langugage to read the CSV, and generate the C source file and calculate offsets automatically. This is very easy to do with something like Python, which has CSV file routines in standard library.

As an additional bonus, you can also generate new CSV file with calculated offsets that PC software can use. It will be easier for the PC application to parse, and you don't have to modify to parser if you have to change the embedded compiler which uses different pragma syntax.

You can use other file format or scripting language, but basic idea stays the same. You get a new tool requirement, but gain a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The recent support is to set the variables in a region of memory in the flash area with the following pragma directive:

`#pragma default_variable_attributes`

You can do the same for your functions as well:

`#pragma default_function_attributes`

["how to do placement of a group of functions and variables"](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/linker/how-do-i-place-a-group-of-functions-or-variables-in-a-specific-section/)